# Is it possible to use Azure Schema registry with HDInsights?

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-hdinsight

I would like to know if Azure HDInsights Kafka is compatible with Azure Event Registry.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka just stores bytes. Therefore, it both doesn't require a registry and can work with *any* registry, including more than one at a time.

The client's are what integrate with the registries, not really the brokers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/schema-registry-concepts#client-sdks